# How to fix 'str' object has no attribute 'read' in my python3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I fix AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' error in my python3 script.

```
user = input("Enter your word : ")
script = open('wordlist.txt', "r")

for s in script:
    content = s.read()
    if user in content:
        print("Match")
    else:
        print("Not match")
```

Comment: `content = script.read()` and lose the for loop

Comment: `read()` is a files' method but you call it on `s` which is a string representing each row of the file. Either change to `if user in s` in the loop or simply `if user in script.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for the whole file at once

```
user = input("Enter your word : ")
script = open('wordlist.txt', "r")

if user in script.read():
    print("Match")
else:
    print("Not match")
```

Comment: Try changing the 'if user in content:' to 'if s in content'. Otherwise it's quite unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: How can i iterate text file on loop? Please tell me @Tomerikoo

Comment: @Dave please try to do some basic research. This is such a common problem in Python with literally thousands of resources online. You have one link above that should help you

Comment: @Tomerikoo then he might as well do 'if user in script.readlines():' right?

Comment: @Dave I edited the solution please check if it works now